# xdebug - waiting for connection in netbeans

Tags: netbeans, port, xdebug

I am using Netbeans to debug PHP. I dont have access to `php.ini` so I use `.htaccess`:

```
php_value   xdebug.remote_host   "localhost"    
php_value   xdebug.idekey               "netbeans-xdebug"
php_flag    xdebug.remote_autostart       Off
php_flag    xdebug.remote_enable          On
php_value   xdebug.remote_port            9000
php_value   xdebug.remote_handler         dbgp
php_flag    xdebug.profiler_enable        on
php_flag    xdebug.remote_connect_back    On
php_flag    xdebug.extended_info          On
```

`sub.mydomain.com` runs with port 8080 and 8090. I have previously used xdebug with Eclipse on this server.

The `sub.mydomain.com` server 's `phpinfo()` lists xdebug as installed together with the settings above:

```
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2011 Zend Technologies
with Xdebug v2.1.3, Copyright (c) 2002-2012, by Derick Rethans
```

In Netbeans I have configured the "properties" and "run configuration" entries and port and id match also (9000, netbeans-xdebug).

There are many developers on `sub.mydomain.com`, might this be a problem if anyone uses port 9000?

Still if I run "debug" in Netbeans, there comes "Waiting for connection" forever.

What do I have to do?

Edit: fixed to localhost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to start the debugger with the following config:

```
php_value   xdebug.remote_host   "192.168.1.149"
php_value   error_reporting               22527
php_flag    xdebug.remote_autostart       Off
php_flag    xdebug.remote_enable          On
php_value   xdebug.remote_port            9009
php_value   xdebug.remote_handler         dbgp
php_value   xdebug.remote_log             "..."
php_flag    xdebug.profiler_enable        off
php_flag    xdebug.extended_info          On
php_flag    xdebug.coverage_enable        On
php_value   error_log                     "..."
```

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong:

```
php_value   xdebug.remote_host   "sub.mydomain.com"
```

the xdebug.remote_host setting needs to contain the IP of the machine that has your *IDE* on it. This of course also means that the machine running PHP/Xdebug needs to be able to connect to that IP address. This is also documented at http://xdebug.org/docs/remote#communication

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have edited the `remote_host` to my IP of IDE 192.168.1.149, but still it does not work.

Comment: What does show up in your remote debug log (See http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_log on how to make one)

Comment: Thanks for the msg. The file is empty, always. The path is correct and chmod 777. What else can I check to find the cause?